# Domain not getting resolved on certain clients randomly

Tags: dns

I am having trouble with some clients where they say they randomnly cannot access the site, but other times they does. I haven’t taken too much time on it because I always thought it was something related with their DNS server, but now I am facing the same problem with internal api requests to the public domain of the server and I am afraid something related with the DNS provider.

EDIT: The requests are performed using curl php extension, and not all of the requests crashes, just some of them. When they crashes I get this: CURL error - 6: Could not resolve host: example.com. But if inmediately I connect via ssh the machine to repeat the request or repeat the request manually, it works, but I fails some of the time, not always.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of research have you done and what have you tried so far? There are so many possible causes, more information is needed in order to help you.  [How to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have added more info

Comment: Logs? DNS testing? Trace route?